# How to prevent canvas drawing to be erased on next mousedown?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, ionic3

I am on Ionic 3 angular V5, I couldn't use the Viewchild which returns a undefined, so I used ViewChildren et get the first item of the array (dirty I know)

```
@ViewChildren('imageCanvas') canvas: any;
public canvasElement: any;
saveX: number;
saveY: number;
public drawing = false;
selectedColor: '#9e2956';
lineWidth: 5;

startDrawing(ev) {
    if (this.canvasElement === undefined) {
        this.canvasElement = this.canvas._results[0].nativeElement;
        console.log('always there')
    }
    this.canvasElement.width = this.plt.width() + '';
    this.canvasElement.height = 200;

    const canvasPosition = this.canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    let currentX = ev.pageX - canvasPosition.x;
    let currentY = ev.pageY - canvasPosition.y;
    this.saveX = currentX;
    this.saveY = currentY;

    this.drawing = true
}

moved(ev) {
    if (!this.drawing) return


    const canvasPosition = this.canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    //console.log('canvasPosition ', canvasPosition)

    let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');

    let currentX = ev.pageX - canvasPosition.x;
    let currentY = ev.pageY - canvasPosition.y;

    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectedColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.saveX, this.saveY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.stroke();

    this.saveX = currentX;
    this.saveY = currentY;


}
```

When I inish a line, I release the button, and drawing again will erase the previous drawing

Comment: Setting canvas elements size eg `this.canvasElement.height = 200` clears the canvas, even if the size is unchanged.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks that solved my problem, i'd be happy to accept your answer if you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resetting 2D context state

When you set the canvas size the 2D state is reset to default. This includes all the pixels, which are set to default `transparent` (or `black` if you used `{alpha: false}` when getting the context).

In addition all the 2D settings like `fillStyle`, `font`, `transform`, etc... are reset to default.

Any saved states via `ctx.save` are also removed.

This will happen with any write to the canvas `width` or `height` properties.

eg The following will reset the canvas state.

```
 canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

In your call `startDrawing` you set the canvas `width` and `height` which is the reason your canvas is being cleared at every mouse down event.